# Add "-" for every word - javascript

Tags: javascript

For every word that is entered into the text box I want to add a "-" before each word except for words like "is" and "was".

```
$('#WhatTextBox').keyup(function() {
        var word_check = $('#WhatTextBox').val();
        if(!word_check.match('is') OR !word_check.match(' ')) {

            $('#special'("-"+$('#WhatTextBox').val());

}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: In the if clause also add a condition whether a '-' is present, if not done, you will append the character for every key up

Comment: This will treat complete value as word_check. Whereas you want to add hyphen before every word in value. 

Are you sure you do not want to split the value based on separators?

Comment: `$('#WhatTextBox').val()` is a really inefficient way to write `this.value`.

Comment: @D3V I dont want to separate but just add the "-" before each entered word or as the word is entered.

SashiKant I dont understand.

Comment: "*What am I missing here?*" If done on key up, how do you know that " wa" is going to be " was" or " water" so whether to add a leading "-" or not?

Comment: @RobG Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Comment: @RobG What do you suggest?

Comment: `OR` in javascript must be `||`

Comment: Do you want to replace the contents of the text area, or do the dom selection only?

Comment: @QuentinEngles Dont want to replace but add before each word "-" and not before select words such as 'is' etc.

Comment: @X10nD—take the advice of your console and stop trying to call a string. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#WhatTextBox').keyup(function() {
            var text = $(this).val();
            text = text.split(" ");
            var newtext = "";
            for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
                if (text[i] == 'is' || text[i] == 'was'){
                    newtext = newtext+" "+text[i];
                }else{
                    newtext = newtext+"-"+text[i];
                }
            }
            $("#newtext").text(newtext);
        });             
    });
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id='WhatTextBox'></textarea>
<div id='newtext'></div>
```

Or if you have some special words, you can use this javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var specialwords = ['is','was','am','are'];//special words here
        $('#WhatTextBox').keyup(function() {
            var text = $(this).val();
            text = text.split(" ");
            var newtext = "";
            for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
                if (specialwords.indexOf(text[i])!=-1){
                    newtext = newtext+" "+text[i];
                }else{
                    newtext = newtext+"-"+text[i];
                }
            }
            $("#newtext").text(newtext);
        });             
    });
```

Comment: I've added the answer

Comment: -adf-dfwe was-dw are need space between "-adf" and "-dfwe"  These words are called by newtext = newtext+"-"+text[i]?

Comment: yes, you can add space there like this `newtext = newtext+" -"+text[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use replace method?

```
$('#WhatTextBox').keyup(function() {
        $('#WhatTextBox').val($('#WhatTextBox').val().replace(' ', '-').replace('-is', ' Is').replace('-was', ' was'));
}
```

Comment: That was easy, how do I check if that particular word is 'is' or 'and'?

Comment: So no hyphen for 'issued'?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already answered, but I figured why not. Some one might like this other method.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="WhatTextBox">
</textarea>
<script>

$('#WhatTextBox').keyup(function() {
    var val = ' '+this.value;
    var exempt = ['is', 'was'];
    var value = val.replace(/(\s)([\S]+)/g, function(m, space, word){

        var tmp = word.slice(1, word.length);
        if(exempt.indexOf(tmp) !== -1){
            return space+tmp;
        }else if(exempt.indexOf(word) !== -1 || word[0] === '-'){
            return space+word;
        }

        return space+'-'+word;
    });

    this.value = value.slice(1, value.length);
});
</script>
```